# Android - How to add different spacing for different characters in a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, character, letter, letter-spacing

On Android, one can use the `android:letterSpacing` XML attribute or the `setLetterSpacing(float letterSpacing)` method to change the spacing between *ALL* characters in a TextView.

Is there a way to change the spacing ***per character***? For instance, for the string: 123456789 I want the TextView to display it like this:

12 3456 789

In other words, I just want to change the spacing between the 2nd and the 3rd characters and between the 6th and the 7th characters.

Comment: Insert a space into the string.

Comment: Seems like you want phone number formatting, check this library https://github.com/google/libphonenumber

Comment: That was just an example guys... In iOS you can set up different spacing per character. I wonder if you can do the same in Android. I can't find anything in the docs about it.

Comment: You can use regex as per your spacing, to convert your original string.